# Question about sorting 2 dimensional array in Golang

Tags: arrays, sorting, go, type-2-dimension

I have a question about 2 dimensional array in GoLang. I do not know why the sort method I use does not work, but It works well in java, C, and C++, but I am not sure what is wrong when I applied the same sort method in Golang, sometimes it give me the right result, sometimes, it does not sort at all. Please help. Thank you so much in advance.

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
)

var employee int = 0
var day int = 1

func main() {

   list := [][] int {{2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8},
                     {7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4},
                     {3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2},
                     {9, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1},
                     {3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8},
                     {3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4},
                     {3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 4},
                     {6, 3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9}}

   var result [8][2] int 

   for i := 0; i < len(result); i++ {

       var total int = 0

       for j := 0; j < len(list[i]); j++ {
          total += list[i][j]
       }

       result[i][employee] = i 
       result[i][day] = total
   }

   sort(result)

   fmt.Println("The decreasing order is:")

   for i := 0; i < len(result); i++ {

       fmt.Printf("Employee %v's total dayoff is %v\n", result[i][employee], result[i][day])
    }
}

func sort(list[8][2] int) {

    for i := 0; i < len(list); i++ {

        var max_day int = list[i][day]
        var max_employee int = list[i][employee]
        var max_index int = i 

        for j := i + 1; j < len(list); j++ {

            if list[j][day] > max_day {
                max_day = list[j][day]
                max_employee = list[j][employee]
                max_index = j
            }
        }

        if max_index != i {
            list[max_index][employee] = list[i][employee]
            list[max_index][day] = list[i][day]
            list[i][employee] = max_employee
            list[i][day] = max_day
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Go has also a [sort](https://pkg.go.dev/sort) package in the stdlib.

Answer (score 3):

You're modifying a copy of `list` in your `sort()` function, change its prototype to:

```
func sort(list *[8][2]int) {
```

and call it:

```
sort(&result)
```

Comment: @VietNguyen, why dont you accept the answer then?

Comment: can you please explain how "sometimes it give me the right result, sometimes, it does not sort at all." I think it should not sort at all unless he use pointer as parameter or return new slice. write?